# Ms Access Send Email the Report as image in body of the email

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to send my MS access report in body of the email(Image format) not as an attachment. 
I just have an idea that we need to export that particular report as jpg format and copy, paste that into body of the email but i don't have VBA code.
Any one please give me some direction.

Comment: Why would one do this, or does the report just contain images no text? I would suggest exporting to HTML and put this in body and attach it as pdf too.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher  my report contains images so I need that report as a image in body of the email, is that possible in html?

Comment: And what happends on HTML-Expot?  Where are the images stored?  Copy them from there?

Comment: Can you suggest a VBA code for this?